# w32tm do not sync with configured Ntp server (source is clock)

Tags: windows, time, ntp

On an Windows 10 workstation configured to connect to a local time server(the peerlist contains only one NTP server present in the local network). But when inspecting the configuration with "w32tm /query /source" the source is still Local CMOS clock.
Why is not the source equal to the address from the peerlist?
The NTP server is available and time could be requested (checked with AboutTime which displays the difference between current host and a local or remote NTP server). Also checked displaying the difference between workstation and NTP server. The difference remain constant when checking with the command:

`w32tm /stripchart computer: <LocalNTPserverName>`

Even after some hours, so it is clear that the time is not aligned with NTP server.
The current peer configuration is:

`w32tm /query /peers`

```
Peer: <LocalNTPserverName>,0x9
State: Pending
Time Remaining: 0.0000000s
Mode: 0 (reserved)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
```

But the source is CMOS clock:

`w32tm /query /source`

```
Local CMOS Clock
```

I would like to add that the workstation is not in a domain and it is not virtual machine.

Finally, if you need the full configuration is:

`w32tm /query /configuration`

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 30000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Policy)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Policy)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 0 (Policy)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Policy)
Type: NTP (Policy)
NtpServer: <LocalNTPserverName>,0x9 (Policy)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to perform the following commands in PowerShell as an admin:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net stop w32time
```

The NTP source for my system was the primary domain controller. The `w32tm /unregister` command removes the entire `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time` hive and the `w32tm /register` command then replaces it with the defaults, which causes it to use the PDC of the domain it is a part of.

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: In your case, initial status was the same (trying to connect to other NTP server (non PDC) but the status mentioned Local CMOS clock)?

Comment: Yes my system showed `(local)` configuration but *not* `NT5DS` which means it wasn't using AD time sync. This was a member server, but workstations can be configured in much the same way. My network has 3 GPS stratum 0 devices which act as stratum 1 servers. Hope this helps!